# Dependency Injection of static class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am beginning my career as a developer. In the code I am using simple `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` to serialize one object into JSON before sending it, the code looks like this `JsonSerializer.Serialize(message, options: serializerOptions)`.
I got a suggestion to inject the JsonSerializer class so I can change it later or play with the serializer options during tests. How do I do that? It sounds easy, but JsonSerializer is a static class and I don't know how to get over it.

One idea I had is to create an interface and class that would look something like this:

```cs
public interface ISerializer
{
    public string Serialize(object o, object settings);
    public object Deserialize<T>(string s, object settings);
}

public class Serializer : ISerializer
{
    public object Deserialize<T>(string s, object settings) =>
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(s, options: settings as JsonSerializerOptions);

    public string Serialize(object o, object settings) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(o,options: settings as JsonSerializerOptions);
}
```

And then I'd inject that `Serializer` class, but it doesn't seem right. What is the best approach here?

Comment: I would say that your proposed solution is *the* way to decouple a consumer from a static class such as `JsonSerializer`.

Comment: @RyanWilson I think there is a reason to it. First of all, as I got in suggestion, I could change the serializer settings in test project.
Second of all, that serializer will actually be called few times in different places. What if I'd like to change to JsonSoft or even our own implementation of json serializer?

Comment: @Fllipson There are plenty of overloads of the `Serialize` and `Deserialize` methods already available, this seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a completely normal way of doing things: wrapping concrete classes (static or otherwise) and extracting an interface.

I think what you have is fine.

It will allow you to change out the implementation altogether should you so choose. The interface can also be mocked for unit tests if you want to test the behavior of something dependent on your interface.